# Simplify multiple inheriting classes (with all same content) of abstract class

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I like to count multiple things in my app and save the value to android sharedpreferences. Everything works, but I am not satisfied with the class design in general.

Very simple abstract class. Class parameter is used to name keys in sharedPreferences.

```
public abstract class Counter {

    private Context mContext;
    private Class mClass;

    Counter(Class myClass, Context context) {
        this.mClass = myClass;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return PrefManager.with(mContext).getInt(mClass.getName(), 0);
        //return UniversalPreferences.getInstance().get(counterName, 1);
    }

    public void increment() {
        PrefManager.with(mContext).save(mClass.getName(), getValue() + 1);
        //UniversalPreferences.getInstance().put(counterName, getCurrentValue(counterName) + 1);
    }
}
```

So far I have already 5 classes inheriting from Counter with all the same content.

```
public class CounterAppLaunch extends Counter {

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private static CounterAppLaunch instance;

    private CounterAppLaunch(Context context) {
        super(CounterAppLaunch.class, context);
    }

    public static CounterAppLaunch getInstance(Context context) {
        if(CounterAppLaunch.instance == null) {
            CounterAppLaunch.instance = new CounterAppLaunch(context);
        }
        return CounterAppLaunch.instance;
    }
}
```

I have counters I like to call from different classes and increment there (eg. CounterAPICall or CounterOnResumeCallExample). Which works with this code just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code might be useful to retrieve an appropriate counter:

```
public Counter{
    private int count;

    public Counter(){
        count = 0;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return count;
    }

    public void increment(){
        counter++;
    }
}

public CounterStorage(){
    private static HashMap<String, Counter> counterMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static Counter getInstance(String str){
        if (counterMap.containsKey(str)) return counterMap.get(str);

        Counter newCounter = new Counter();
        counterMap.add(str, newCounter);
        return newCounter;

    }
}
```

In this case, Counter isn't an abstract class. For any purpose, you can give a Counter a name, which is stored in the map.

Comment: This will not work in my case. I like to call the same counter from every class I like. With this example a call of CounterStorage.getInstance(MyClassA, Context) and CounterStorage.getInstance(MyClassB, Context) will result in two different counters. With my existing code I get the same counter and value from everywhere.

Comment: Edited my question to match this requirement.

Comment: But still I will upvote this. The counterMap approach can help me elsewhere.

Comment: So, you'd like to to get a global counter, but a seperate count for each class?

Comment: I like to have multiple global counters.

Comment: okay, can u pls explain, why exactly the above code isnt working? don't get it quite. For each class, a seperate counter is created if required?

Comment: Let's say I have a counter that counts every call of onResume application wide. If I call CounterStorage.getInstance(ClassA).increment() a new counter is created and incremented. I then call CounterStoreage.getInstance(ClassB).increment another counter is created. Two counters, same purpose, two times number one instead of two. From my code I can just create another class CounterOnResume extends Counter and count every onResume call app wide.

Comment: okay, updated the solution. instead of string, one can use any qualifier which identifies the counter uniquely

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Dependency injection and having HasA also, we can try,

```
public class CounterAppLaunch{
    @Autowired
    CounterAdapter counterAdapter;
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private static CounterAppLaunch instance;

    private CounterAppLaunch(Context context) {
        super(CounterAppLaunch.class, context);
    }

    public static CounterAppLaunch getInstance(Context context) {
        if(CounterAppLaunch.instance == null) {
            CounterAppLaunch.instance = new CounterAppLaunch(context);
        }
        return CounterAppLaunch.instance;
    }
}

CounterAdapter extends Counter{
    @Autowired
    private Context mContext;
    @Autowired
    private Class mClass;
    // getter and setter
}

public abstract class Counter {


    private Context mContext;

    private Class mClass;

    Counter(Class myClass, Context context) {
        this.mClass = myClass;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return PrefManager.with(mContext).getInt(mClass.getName(), 0);
        //return UniversalPreferences.getInstance().get(counterName, 1);
    }

    public void increment() {
        PrefManager.with(mContext).save(mClass.getName(), getValue() + 1);
        //UniversalPreferences.getInstance().put(counterName, getCurrentValue(counterName) + 1);
    }
}
```